# Independence of observations assumption

Tags: t-test, chi-squared-test

Noob here.

I have a dataset with multiple observations per person. Each observation pertains to instances where a person visits the doctor. I created an outcome variable based on the amount of time that has elapsed before the next doctor visit: 1 if the next visit is within 6 months and 0 otherwise. There are also a number of demographic variables (gender, race, etc) on the dataset.

Is there any scenario where a statistical test like ttest or chisquare can be performed with these data without flattening to person level? 
Could I for example test for a relationship between the outcome and say, gender, even though possible that a person could have a different outcome depending on the date of their next doctor visit?

Comment: What do you mean by "flattening"?

Comment: @PeterFlom restructure the dataset such that there is only one observation per person.

Comment: In other words can a stat test like ttest or chisq be used only when there is one observation per person? I ask because I’m wondering if running these tests on a dataset with multiple observations per person violates the independence of observations assumption...which I’m not sure I understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your comments, I see your concern and it is justified. If you have multiple observations per person then you do, indeed, have a violation of independence. There are ways to deal with this. One common method is multi-level models.

Comment: Thank you. I’ll do some digging into multi level models.